# Required Admin Role for provisioning Microsoft Teams Multi tenant custom app

Tags: microsoft-teams

We have a multi tenant custom app and we provide .zip package and instruct the tenant admin to use the Global Admin login to Microsoft Teams Admin portal (https://admin.teams.microsoft.com/)'s Teams apps --> Manage apps --> Upload new app to upload the App .

We tried it on Microsoft 365 E5 developer tenant with 'Teams service admin' role and 'Application admin' users, But with 'Teams service admin' role app catalog is not shown and we could not upload the app as it throws 'try again and contact MS Support'. We could not event login to the  https://admin.teams.microsoft.com portal with 'Application admin' user's credentials.

Is there any least privilege admin role available to install the app or it must require 'Global Admin' ?

Comment: Did you checked Custom App upload is enabled in your teams admin center? You can take a look at [manage app policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/teams-app-permission-policies). Please take a look at [Register Multitenant app in AAD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-convert-app-to-be-multi-tenant)

Comment: We are using the 'Global (Org-wide default) policy that has Allow all Microsoft Apps, All all Third-party apps and allow all Custom Apps.

Comment: Update on the 'Teams service admin' role user : Now all the available apps are listed and we can able to upload our custom app using this User. When we tried User Oauth using this user Microsoft says '_Need admin approval_' and '_... needs permission to access resources in your organization that only an admin can grant. Please ask an admin to grant permission to this app before you can use it_' .

Comment: At the same time if we use the Global Admin user to upload the same custom app and to perform the User OAuth with Global Admin credentials then it is working good . Our question is,   1 . Does  'Teams service admin' has the rights to consent the app or not ? 2. If not what admin account is having the rights other than Global Admin ?

Comment: Yes Admin can consent the App.